# Phonegap loading an cached external site

Tags: android, cordova, webview

I have created a sample phonegap application which loads an external URL. The html page uses a CACHE Manifest in which i am caching the main page too.

The first time i can successfully open the page in android browser and the phonegap application. At this time all the files should be cached. And it is getting cached.

So, now i turn off the server and load the pages again.In android browser I am able to see the page and its resources. But the same is not happening in case of webview. I am getting an error cannot open an url.

I am using the following code snippet. I tested it in Samsung galaxy tab, Android OS 3.0. What am i doing wrong?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.loadUrl("http://(192.168.14.46):8080/CacheTest/index.html");

    this.appView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    this.appView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024 * 1024 * 15);  

 this.appView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true); 

    String appCachePath = getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
    this.appView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(appCachePath);
    this.appView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    //this.appView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);      

}
```

Comment: You mean Android OS 3.0 or Galaxy S3 ?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor: Sorry yes Android OS 3.0.

Comment: why did you comment this line `this.appView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true); `?